# Thinkpad Helix DisplayPort output not working

Tags: debian, xorg, intel-graphics, thinkpad, displayport

I have a Thinkpad Helix 2 (2nd. gen) with Ultrabook Pro Keyboard. There is a mini-DisplayPort output on the keyboard part, but I don't get any output from it. (The keyboard can be detached from the Helix/tablet part.)
I tested it with two different miniDP-to-HDMI converter. (The converters worked with a W540  notebook.)

I don't get any changes in xrandr output, or in dmesg when I connect or disconnect the cables.
I don't see any DisplayPort in xrandr output. The eDP1 is the internal screen.

I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253070/240429) that, the miniDP output shows as HDMI2, but if I connect the miniDP-HDMI converter, the HDMI2 is in "disconnected" state also.

- cpu: Intel(R) Processor 5Y10 CPU @ 0.80GHz (Core M-5Y10, Intel® HD Graphics 5300)
- os: Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie) with jessie-backport
- kernel: 4.9.30-2~bpo8+1 x86_64
- xserver-xorg-video-intel: 2:2.99.917+git20161206-1~bpo8+1

`$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 260mm x 140mm
   1920x1080     59.99*+
   1680x1050     59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1368x768      60.00
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00
   960x540       60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       60.00
   640x360       60.00
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

`$ ls -l /sys/class/drm/
összesen 0
card0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
card0-eDP-1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1
card0-HDMI-A-1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1
card0-HDMI-A-2 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2
controlD64 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/controlD64
renderD128 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/renderD128
version`

Do you have any idea why it is not working or what can I do?

Thank you, for your help.

Comment: Does not anyone have any ideas?